# Ionic 3 Project evaluation failed including an error in afterEvaluate {}

Tags: ionic3

Good evening
i have an ionic 3 app which uses FCM for push notifications
I have the android 8 platform installed
when i try to do cordova build command i got the error:

Project evaluation failed including an error in afterEvaluate {}. Run with --stacktrace for details of the afterEvaluate {} error.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

Where:
Script ‘C:\IONIC\AlloPressing\platforms\android\cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated\starter-FCMPlugin.gradle’ line: 16

What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating script.

Cannot invoke method lastIndexOf() on null object

Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 8s

Configure project :app
c:\IONIC\AlloPressing\platforms\android\gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
Project evaluation failed including an error in afterEvaluate {}. Run with --stacktrace for details of the afterEvaluate {} error.

please how to correct this?

Comment: got this issue too. any update? how it solved?

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem today after update my system.

**Method 1:**

Remove the plugin and add again with the correct ANDROID_GRANDLE_TOOLS_VERSION variable:

```
cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated

cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated --variable ANDROID_GRADLE_TOOLS_VERSION="4.1.0"   --variable ANDROID_GOOGLE_SERVICES_VERSION="4.3.4"
```

**Method 2:**

Let's check the error. Open the file and go to line 16

> C:\IONIC\AlloPressing\platforms\android\cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated\starter-FCMPlugin.gradle

Here on my linux the line have the follow content:

```
 ext.gradleNumberVersion = ANDROID_GRADLE_TOOLS_VERSION.substring(0, ANDROID_GRADLE_TOOLS_VERSION.lastIndexOf(".")).toFloat()
```

Looks like is something about ANDROID_GRANDLE_TOOLS_VERSION.

Set the variable. On linux, I use:

```
export ANDROID_GRADLE_TOOLS_VERSION=4.1.0
```

Try to compile again:

```
ionic cordova build android --aot --minifyjs --minifycss --release
```

**PS:** You need provide some information. What is the output for `ionic info`?

**PS:** Those steps I've tried myself on my pc using ubuntu 18:

Ionic:

```
   Ionic CLI          : 6.12.3 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@ionic/cli)
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.3

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 10.0.0
   Cordova Platforms : android 9.0.0
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 1.2.1, (and 29 other plugins)

Utility:

   cordova-res (update available: 0.15.2) : 0.8.1
   native-run                             : 1.3.0

System:

   Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (/home/diego/Android/Sdk)
   NodeJS            : v12.20.0 (/usr/local/bin/node)
   npm               : 6.14.10
   OS                : Linux 5.4
```

**PS:** On [cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated) page you can find a lot of useful information.

**PS:** Probably, you have to comment two lines on the same file:

```
// class must be used instead of id(string) to be able to apply plugin from non-root gradle file
//if (!project.plugins.hasPlugin('com.google.gms.google-services')) {
 //   apply plugin: com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin
//}
```

Let me know if you did. Good Luck!

Comment: The "Method  1" solve my problem, thx!